# Bootstrap 4 – navbar search form min width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

How to make 100% width search form with min-width in Bootstrap 4 navbar?
My markup here: https://jsfiddle.net/bfsrjo23/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
<a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar5">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink1 <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink3</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink4</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink5</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink6</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<form class="w-100 py-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control border" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

I put form outside collapse to make it always visible (laptop in 1st line, mobile in 2nd line). It's work fine exept Tablet mode (Viewport width around 880px), the search box too short. I want to add "min-width" and let form go in second line if size not pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found acceptable solution - key is remove flex-wrap:wrap from  css, for example with @media(min-width:992px), search form must have "display:flex;flex-basis:100%" or "width:100%". This will move search in second line.

Answer (score 0):

Use css like this:

```
#yourformId > .input-group {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: use css like this

Comment: BS4 has d-inline class, but it still ignore min-width (cut width to fit or overflow nav). I want to split search box in second line if min-width is not reached.

Answer (score 0):

Just add class d-inline in nav, like this:

---

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light d-inline bg-faded">
<a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar5">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink1 <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink3</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink4</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink5</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink6</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">LongLink7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<form class="w-100 py-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control border" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

Comment: This will ruin all navbar - it's now in 3 line (logo, menu, search), no background. I want to keep search in first line until it fit min-size, next - move it in second line. Is it possible with BS4 flexbox navbar?

Comment: Yes it is, you can do it like that.